# Firebase Auth - How to mimic client_credentials flow

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, oauth

We are switching from Auth0 to Firebase Auth. For our app, we have email-link and google-auth. However we have a few other systems that need to authenticate to the same backend. Those are in Python.

With Auth0, we had created an 'application' for the 3rd party and gave them the client_id and secret. They then POSTed to our backend using grant_type=client_credentials along with the client_id:secret to get an auth-token which they use in the header for subsequent requests.

What is the equivalent of this in Firebase auth?

To re-cap, I'm looking for something in Firebase auth that I can generate and give to my 3rd party so they can make authenticated requests to my backend.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [creating a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for Firebase. Typically you'd do this on your own trusted environments though, unless the 3rd party has built the logic into their system **and** you are willing to give them access to your administrative credentials for the project.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen They 3rd party is trusted, it's another team in our company. However I don't really want/need them to have Admin access, I just need them to be able to make REST calls to our API with an auth-token.

Comment: Also from what I gather `signInWithCustomToken` is not available in the python admin sdk. So i'm not sure what I would tell the other team to do to get a token.